# How does Neo4J store data?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, storage, disk

I saw this link: 
http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals

And a couple other slideshows, e.g. from University Leipzig. In here, they show how the nodes and relations are modeled.

However, they use the terms:

"SP, SN, EP, EN".

I have gathered they mean "Source Previous, Source Next, End Previous and End Next".

However, I do not understand what all of these terms mean. Also, all the relations in those slides to me *appear* to be the same, yet they are shown to differ on being a *seemingly random* combination of SP, SN, EP, EN.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find any resources which explain these terms. Could anybody point me in the right direction? (i.e. some resources where this is explained?)